# Tweet from users behalf

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, twitter, twitter-oauth

I want to post a tweet using users account.
I have an web page which asks for users login credential for twitter.
Once user made successful login and enters the tweet, I want this tweet to be posted in user's twitter account.
Is it possible. 
If yes, I have fetched the tweets by using twitterVB classes, can I use the same class for this purpose. 
I found some ways of doing this in internet but they are asking for customer_key and key secret, not login information.

Please help. any suggestion or solution will be very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You have to first go to the https://dev.twitter.com/

Create one application over developer account. from their you got the access token and other keys.

you have to use that information into your application,and then twitter will allow you to post a message.

Comment: I already have that. I have all the keys given by twitter api. But I am looking for a way by which I can pass Username and password to api and can post a tweet.

Comment: I have posted a Approch you have to use Twitterizer2.dll

Answer (score 0):

You can use below mentioned Approch

```
        OAuthTokens Token = new OAuthTokens();
        Token.ConsumerKey = twitterdata.AppId;
        Token.ConsumerSecret = twitterdata.AppSecret;
        Token.AccessToken = twitterdata.TokenId;
        Token.AccessTokenSecret = twitterdata.Tokensecret;
        string postedMsgID = TwitterPost(Token, PostMsg, ref strErrorMsg);

 private string TwitterPost(OAuthTokens Token, string PostMsg, ref StringBuilder strErrorMsg)
    {
        log.Info("Start Tweeting At==> " + DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString() + " " + DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString());
        #region Called the Tweeting API for Tweet the News.
        string MsgID = "-1";
            try
            {
                StatusUpdateOptions options = new StatusUpdateOptions();
                options.UseSSL = true;
                TwitterResponse<TwitterStatus> ts = TwitterStatus.Update(Token, PostMsg, options);
                if (ts.ResponseObject != null)
                    MsgID = Convert.ToString(ts.ResponseObject.Id);
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(ts.Content.Trim()))
                {
                    if (ts.Content.Trim().ToLower().Contains("error"))
                    {
                        log.Error(DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString() + "Twitter Error : Occured in posting msg : " + PostMsg + ", Message : " + ts.Content);
                        strErrorMsg.Append(ts.Content);
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                log.Error(DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString() + "Twitter Error : Occured in posting msg : " + PostMsg + ", Message : " + e.Message);
                strErrorMsg.Append(e.Message);
            }


        log.Info("END Tweeting At==> " + DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString() + " " + DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString());
        return MsgID;
        #endregion
    }
```

Comment: @Dhavan If I'll use this method. tweet will be posted from the account of developer (account for which tokens are generated). which I dont want to do. I want any third user to come in my application, Login and post tweet to his/her own account.

Answer (score 0):

You can use below mentioned code:

in button click event

```
window.open("localhost:2401\tweeter.html", ShareURL, 'width=700,height=570');
```

my tweeter.html code looks like

```
<html>
   <head>
    <title></title>
   </head>
<body>
</body>
</html>

<script>
var url = window.opener.ShareURL;

window.location.assign('https://twitter.com/share?text=' +  encodeURIComponent(url).trim() + "&url=", "twitter", 'width=700,height=570');

</script>
```